# Help me identify downtube shifter boss type

Tags: downtube-shifter

I think I received this frame with standard Shimano cable stops, but they don't seem to fit. Also, I couldn't found this shape of downtube bosses anywhere.

The problem seems to be with the non-rectangular shape of the "base" part of the bosses. I can't fit the cable stop over the base, there's a huge gap and the stop can rotate around.

EDIT: I've shown the frame to a local framebuilder who's been in the business since early 90's and he said he's never seen this type before.

[image: boss2]

[image: boss2]

Comment: Was the frame repainted? Perhaps the paint is just too thick to allow the cable stop to fit on.

Comment: @NoahSutherland yes, it has been repainted (sandblasted and repainted). That would explain why I rembember the frame with cable stops on.

Comment: the cable stops come in two varieties; perhaps you have the kind that is meant to fit against a flat surface whereas you need the kind that are curved to sit flush against the tub itself?

Comment: https://simplicityvintagecycles.com/2012/04/09/the-kodiak-saga-continues/

Comment: What kind of frame is it? Any idea of the country of origin, age - it's a strange shifter braze on, any clues might help.

Answer (score 1):

Those look like standard shimano-style downtube shifter bosses.  You would need some downtube shifter levers ending up something like this:

[image]

If you want to use brifters (integrated levers) then you need a pair of bosses to stop the outer, which look something like this:

[image]

With these, the outer cable continues up to the levers either in a graceful arc, or to the bars so it can pass under the bartape.

Comment: The second option is not just for brifters, you could also use them for bar-end shifters

Comment: The problem seems to be with the non-rectangular shape of the "base" part of the bosses. I can't fit the cable stop over the base, there's a huge gap and the stop can rotate around.

Comment: @prasopes the painted almost-circular ridge part on the frame?  I'd expect that to be more of a "fill", and the lever or stop to sit on the unpainted boss that pokes out.  Are you refitting what was on before the paint job, or are they new fittings?   If you have both, compare the old and new to see if the measurements are the same inside.

Comment: This answer is not very helpful. It is clear that OP knows what a downtube shifter is. The question is about compatibility of cable stops and bosses. There is not a single "shimano-style" boss, and if you are referring to the style commonly used for later shimano levers, this one does not match. The base is not square and the boss does not have any cylindrical portion.